# Use : to call sequential variables

Tags: r

I am trying to create a set of dynamic variables, that will can used by other function. An example of what I am try is with combining images. I have the piece that creates the dynamic variables:

```
library(magick)
for(i in 0:19){
    assign(paste0("img_",i), image_red(paste0(i,".jpg")))
}
```

I would like to use the following syntax to all the variables:
`img_out <- image_append(img0:19)`
Is this possible in R, or I am going to have to just loop through the variables?

Comment: No, you can't use the `:` operator like that. In general it's not a great idea to write a bunch of named variables into your global environment in a loop. It would be better to have them all in a list. So instead of your loop you would do: `images <- lapply(0:19, function(i) image_red(paste0(i,".jpg")))` and when you want to do image append you could do something like `lapply(images, image_append)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do what you're trying to do with `image_append(img0:19)`. I would just loop through all the variables. You could also try creating a separate list of the variables and passing that as a parameter to `image_append()` if that's easier. Good luck!